# how to make a blur or a drop shadow on text in andengine?

Tags: android, text, andengine, blur, effect

like in this post [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20478/what-rendering-techniques-would-i-use-to-draw-a-drop-shadow-effect-for-cards-in) by exemple
I have found [this blog](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html) but in Andengine there are no onDraw(Canvas canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example here shows very very clearly how to proceed. But here is the bit you seem to be overlooking: you don't create the shadows dynamically. You create shadow png files and layer them. In Andengine, you can create an instance of the "Entity" Class to act as a holder for your shadow and your card. The you use attachChild(shadow) and attachChild(card) to add your graphics. You can then move the combined card and shadow using the entity parent as a reference.

You can skip the section on making a drop shadow using the onDraw method. use Phothsop or Gimp instead, because Andengine does not use standard Android Views.